# How to evenly add a set of values at the beginning of each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'd like to use bash or awk or anything to do the following. I have a file that looks like:

```
/exec/proc1 ...
/exec/proc1 ...
/exec/proc1 ...
/exec/proc1 ...
/exec/proc1 ...
/exec/proc1 ...
```

and if I say 3 i.e. (0, 1, 2) I'd like to produce a file like:

```
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
```

I then pipe this into `shuf` that will randomize the lines. This is a poor's man solution to load balance across multiple CUDA GPU devices.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it seems to me, at least, that GNU Parallel might be a better way to distribute work over multiple GPUs.

Comment: Without getting too far off from the OP. This file is the input to a map reduce framework. Each line is a map step and this is executed on top of a cluster of servers all having a fix number of GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v n=3 '{print "export DEVICE_ID=" (NR-1)%n "; " $0}' file
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, try with 8 rows and see what happens. But your idea led me to a nice solution i.e. using mod % `awk '{print "export DEVICE_ID=" int(NR%3) "; " $0}' file` Please update and I will accept.

Comment: See my updated answer. You can pass value of `n` to anything and output will be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you say in your comments, why not just let awk generate the random numbers you eventually want, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{srand()} {printf "export DEVICE_ID=%d; %s\n", (n+1)*rand(), $0}' file
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...

$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{srand()} {printf "export DEVICE_ID=%d; %s\n", (n+1)*rand(), $0}' file
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...

$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{srand()} {printf "export DEVICE_ID=%d; %s\n", (n+1)*rand(), $0}' file
export DEVICE_ID=0; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
```

or if you need to always have about the same number of 1s, 2s, and 3s in your output you could use the Knuth Shuffle (see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#AWK).

```
$ cat tst.awk
# Shuffle an _array_ with indexes from 1 to _len_.
function shuffle(array, len,    i, j, t) {
        for (i = len; i > 1; i--) {
                # j = random integer from 1 to i
                j = int(i * rand()) + 1

                # swap array[i], array[j]
                t = array[i]
                array[i] = array[j]
                array[j] = t
        }
}

BEGIN { srand(); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) array[i]=i }
{
    idx = (NR-1) % n + 1
    if (idx == 1) {
        shuffle(array, n)
    }
    printf "export DEVICE_ID=%d; %s\n", array[idx], $0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
$ 
$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
$ 
$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=2; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=1; /exec/proc1 ...
export DEVICE_ID=3; /exec/proc1 ...
```